# Can't access File from d Drive while running JBOSS in Drive C as windows service

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jboss, jboss-eap-7

I'm running JBOS EAP 7.4 in C drive as windows service.

- Spring MVC Application war file is in standalone/deployments folder,
- Application supposed to store and access file from D drive.
- While running, application is not able to find the file.

If I run the JBoss from command line everything works fine, application accesses the file from D without any error.

Both drives and folders in these drives have assigned all accesses.

Is there any configuration required for windows service set-up?